# what exactly does CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE do

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, calayer, cgrect

In my project I'm getting a lot of crashes for

> CALayerInvalidGeometry; CALayer bounds contains NaN:

but I am not able to reproduce the crash and only pick it up in Fabric so it's not possible to share the code here as I can't upload my entire project.

From Fabric I get the following message.

> Heads Up! CALayerInvalidGeometry; CALayer bounds contains NaN: [...]
>   Details: This crash is likely due to a division by zero when applying
>   a transform to a view or layer. Setting the
>   'CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE' environment variable in Xcode can help
>   pinpoint the root cause. Check out the references below for more
>   details.

What exactly does setting CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE to YES do?

What can I search for in my project as likely causes of it? Is it enough to just search for all CGRect in the projects?

**How could I create this crash in a test app?**

I tried the following to reproduce it

```
var bounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
let int = apiToken != nil ? 0 : 5
bounds.size = CGSize(width: 5/int, height: 5)
self.bounds = bounds
```

but just got a division by zero error.

Here is the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: CALayerInvalidGeometry
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1856b7d38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184bcc528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1856b7c80 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  QuartzCore                     0x18969d8ac CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool)
4  QuartzCore                     0x18968f730 -[CALayer setBounds:]
5  UIKit                          0x18f1ee7ec __27-[_UILabelLayer setBounds:]_block_invoke
6  UIKit                          0x18f1ee588 -[_UILabelLayer _setFrameOrBounds:settingAction:]
7  UIKit                          0x18f1ee798 -[_UILabelLayer setBounds:]
8  QuartzCore                     0x18968fe28 -[CALayer setFrame:]
9  UIKit                          0x18f1ee6fc __26-[_UILabelLayer setFrame:]_block_invoke
10 UIKit                          0x18f1ee588 -[_UILabelLayer _setFrameOrBounds:settingAction:]
11 UIKit                          0x18f1ee6a8 -[_UILabelLayer setFrame:]
12 UIKit                          0x18eac0818 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:]
13 UIKit                          0x18eacfd54 -[UILabel setFrame:]
14 UIKit                          0x18f64cacc -[_UITAMICAdaptorView layoutSubviews]
15 UIKit                          0x18eac4000 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
16 QuartzCore                     0x1896950b4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
17 QuartzCore                     0x189699194 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
18 QuartzCore                     0x189607f24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
19 QuartzCore                     0x18962e340 CA::Transaction::commit()
20 QuartzCore                     0x18962f180 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18565f8b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18565d270 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18565d82c __CFRunLoopRun
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18557e2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
25 GraphicsServices               0x18740ff84 GSEventRunModal
26 UIKit                          0x18eb2a880 UIApplicationMain
27 ProjectName                    0x1001efe98 main (AppDelegate.swift:21)
28 libdyld.dylib                  0x1850a256c start
```